# Joining multiple tables -better performance and accurate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have few tables in my SQL Server.

[image: see below image with tables and sample data]

I need a result as follows

[image: result]

The result should contain the employee details from checkout table with matching records from other table

I have written following script

```
select  <columns from different tables>  from  Checkin i 
inner join Checkout o on i.EmpCode=o.EmpCode
inner join Employee e on i.EmpCode=e.EmpCode
inner join City c on i.CityId=c.CityId
inner join Building b on i.BuildingId=b.BuildingcoId
```

Is this the correct way? Will it include duplicate values?

Comment: for the following result i understand data can be picked up from checkout table . but in some cases i have to pickup data from checkin table also.

Comment: You have main table checkout, not checkin:) checkout should be first table. And you should join other tables with checkout. Next you shoud consider use left join.

Comment: @mrsWhite Thank you for suggestions. I understand. But in general situations, if there are 4 tables and you join tab1 and tab2 with inner join on a common column from tab1 and tab2. But if tab3 doesnt have a common column with tab2 then can we join tab3 with tab1 using inner join. same way if tab4 doesnt have common column with tab3 and tab2 then?



select from tab1 inner join tab2 on tab1.c1=tab2.c1
inner join tab3 on tab3.c7=tab1.c7
inner join tab4 on tab4.c9=tab1.c9

is that ok?

Comment: Maybe you should make first query join checkin  left join building left join city,next second query checkout   left join building left join city and end select distinct * from (query 1 union all query 2)

Comment: From your expected output Table Building can be ommited from the Query.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "Will it include duplicate values?" - did you get duplicates in your results?

Comment: @mrsWhite Do you mean something like 
------
select * from 

select <cols> from checkin left join building on checkin .c1=building  .c1 left join city on city.c7=checkin.c7 

union all

select <cols> from checkout left join building on checkout .c1=building  .c1 left join city on city.c7=checkout.c7

Comment: select distinct* from 
(
select <cols> from checkin 
left join building on checkin .c1=building .c1 
left join city on checkin.c7 =city.c7
union all 
select <cols> from checkout 
left join building on checkout.c1=building.c1 
left join city on checkout.c7=city.c7) a

Comment: Thank you @mrsWhite i will try and let you know

Comment: Since all the join columns are unique, no you won't get duplicate values. But why not test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all checkouts, start with that table and use outer joins.  Then, check the `JOIN` conditions:

```
select  <columns from different tables> 
from CheckOut co left join
     Checkin ci 
     on co.cinid = ci.cinid left join
     Employee e 
     on e.EmpCode = co.EmpCode left join
     City c
     on c.CityId = co.CityId left join
     Building b
     on b.BuildingId = co.BuildingId;
```

Note that the `join` conditions are to `CheckOut` rather than `CheckIn`.